# Is it possible for performance to suffer if you repeatedly pause/resume a thread?

Tags: multithreading

If yes, please provide an example.

For example, when we resume our thread, the time it takes for it to retrieve and reinitialize the current state might take so much time that we're better off not interrupting the thread at all. Is this a valid example?

Comment: How and why would you want to pause/resume your thread? Why don't you just wait/block on an event in the thread?

Answer (score 0):

Short answear is Yes, almost everything you do with threads introduces some type of overhead, but in most cases if you decide to use multithreading it is because this cost is easily justifiable. Stopping and resuming a thread implies some context switches that only introduce overhead to the application.

Stopping and resuming threads should be used carefully as in this [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

For other runtime environments this may vary, the doc is simply about concurrency within Java, other environments may differ.

Some quotes from Oracle Documentation regarding dangers and deprecation of some methods to resume and pause threads. These are not so much performance issues but conception problems and bugs.

- Why are Thread.suspend and Thread.resume deprecated?

> Thread.suspend is inherently deadlock-prone. If the target thread holds a lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource when it is suspended, no thread can access this resource until the target thread is resumed. If the thread that would resume the target thread attempts to lock this monitor prior to calling resume, deadlock results. Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen" processes.

- Why is Thread.stop deprecated?

> Because it is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread causes it to unlock all the monitors that it has locked. (The monitors are unlocked as the ThreadDeath exception propagates up the stack.) If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, other threads may now view these objects in an inconsistent state. Such objects are said to be damaged. When threads operate on damaged objects, arbitrary behavior can result. This behavior may be subtle and difficult to detect, or it may be pronounced. Unlike other unchecked exceptions, ThreadDeath kills threads silently; thus, the user has no warning that his program may be corrupted. The corruption can manifest itself at any time after the actual damage occurs, even hours or days in the future.